# Screen is not rendered using Modal in a screen of a Tab Navigator

Tags: react-native, modal-dialog, navigator

I am having an issue while using TabNavigator.

Here is my App.js

```
render(){

    if (!this.state.loaded) {
      return <AppLoading onFinish={() => this.setState({ loaded: true })} />;
    }

    return (
      <Navigation style={{ flex: 1 }}/>
    );
  }
```

where the first tab of my navigator looks like this :

```
render() {
  <View style={{ flex: 1, backgroundColor: 'red' }}>
     <Modal ...>
       ...
     </Modal>
  </View>
}
```

The problem with this (using Expo Client) my View with the red background is not rendered, but the modal actually is. So I have my Splashscreen as background and my modal as foreground...

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

you should have a single return in render method, if the condition is true only AppLoading Component will be returned and Navigation Component will not be rendered, so change the above code as following.

```
render() {

return (
      <Navigation style={{ flex: 1 }}/>
      {!this.state.loaded &&
        <AppLoading onFinish={() => this.setState({ loaded: true })} />;
      }
    );

}
```

Comment: it changes nothing actually, since in javascript once a return is called it kills the function...